# Logback log file rotation policy

Tags: logback

I am using the following in logback.xml. This is keeping only 21 files and removing older log files. Can anyone please suggest how the file removal can be stopped?

```
<appender name="MY_UPDATES_APPENDER"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!--See also http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender -->
    <File>logs/upilogs/upi-app.log
    </File>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/upilogs/my-app.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>50</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>%d %X %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%ex</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [feature](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FixedWindowRollingPolicy) of logback. Quoting from the linked URL

> Given that the fixed window rolling policy requires as many file
>   renaming operations as the window size, large window sizes are
>   strongly discouraged. When large values are specified by the user, the
>   current implementation will automatically reduce the window size to
>   20.